# ADUC object keeps returning

Tags: active-directory

Within ADUC after turning on View -> "Advanced Features" and "Users [...] as containers" and clicking on a user, the right pane shows the users' objects.

I am trying to delete one called "OTS Protected Storage" (Digital Persona software). Steps:

1. Right click -> Delete
2. "Are you sure you want to delete the dpUserSecret named 'OTS Protected Storage'"
3. Yes
4. Object is gone
5. Refresh pane, object is still gone
6. Check other DCs, object is gone (thus the change replicated)

But as soon as this user logs into any PC again on the domain, the object returns and the data stored also returns.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If I [google Digital Persona Software](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital%20persona%20software), it looks like software/drivers related to a fingerprint scanner on the PC. The object it's creating on the account is likely storage for the fingerprint metadata for that user.

The object is likely harmless and probably required if you actually want to use fingerprint scanning for AD logon. But if you really want it to stop getting created, you need to get rid of the software that's creating it.

Comment: The goal is to reset the stored credentials. It's okay if the object comes back eventually without any data, but even the data stored within this object keeps returning. So far I'm at a loss how AD keeps recovering the same data.

Comment: I would ask the vendor.

Comment: Yep been working with them, they told me to delete this AD object to do so and it keeps returning. Still working with them, but no solution yet.